# jquery autogrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I know that combining two framework prototype and jquery is not a good idea. But I already a lot of code made by prototype, But when I discovered jquery I decided to use this because there is some methods and functions advances than prototype.

My question is I was using jquery autogrow but it was not work if I am using prototype at the same time. Even I was followed the jquery instructions regarding "using jquery with other libraries"

any help would greatly appreciated

in the head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autogrow.js"></script>
<script> 
jQuery.noConflict()
jQuery(document).ready (function() {

jQuery('#expanding').autogrow({
    maxHeight: 100,
    minHeight: 30,
    lineHeight: 16
});

});
</script>
```

in the body

```
<body>
    <textarea name="" cols="50" rows="" id="expanding"></textarea>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you have the latest version of autogrow from http://plugins.jquery.com/project/autogrow. There is a minor bug in that version that prevents it from working when you're using prototype.
It's simple fix; the error is on [line 103](https://gist.github.com/203735/95f10a55df7199234e723e2849bbd076aff552b1#LC103) of jquery.autogrow.js

You need to change:

```
if ($.browser.msie)
```

to:

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie)
```

Your code should work once you fix that.

**P.S.** Please remember to add comments or edit your question, when appropriate, instead of adding an answer - the 'answer' you just added is not technically an answer.

Comment: hi brianpeiris,

Thank you so much, it works like a charm. Your the great!

sorry for not properly using add comment. 

Tirso

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you should always use the `type` attribute with `<script>` tags. You should make sure you end each line with a semicolon ;)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including prototype after jquery and jquery.autogrow in your sequence of script includes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the css padding and line-height:

```
textarea {
  padding:4px;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:14px
}
```

this one works.